# Click table cell to generate chart

Tags: vba, excel

How can I generate a chart by clicking a table cell, Range(“A2”) in my case?

Got this going so far:

```
Sub ClickCell()

    Dim my_range    As Range

    Set my_range = Selection
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=my_range
    Range(“A2”).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Does that code properly generate your chart?

Comment: No, It doesn’t seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give much detail but this should get you started...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ch
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then 'if the cell click was B2...
        'deletes all charts on worksheet
        For Each ch In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            ch.Delete
        Next ch

        'create new chart using the data at A1:C8
        Range("A1:C8").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkers).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$C$8")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is a **worksheet-level module**, so make sure it goes in the spot: 
- Right-click the "tab" for the worksheet (the one where "B2" is located), then click `View Code`.
- Paste the code there
- Adapt as necessary.

Now each time you click `B2`, any existing charts will be deleted, and a new one added in it's place.  You'll obviously need to adapt this to your needs.

I think there are some things you still need to consider; for exanple, your code is using the `.Selection` as the source data... but you want the code to run specifically when the `.Selection` is **changed**, to a single cell (`B2`)...

Comment: I’ll tinker around with that. TYSM